# how to access an li tag in apache wicket

Tags: wicket

This seems a little trivial but I am not sure how to access an li tag from wicket API. Imagine I have an html code like:

```
...
<li wicket:id="L1"><a wicket:id="A1">/<a></li>
...
```

how can I get the reference to li line there and set an attribute based on whatever logic in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebMarkupContainer seems to be good enough for accessing li html tag.